# How to change the hyperlink color in a leaflet popup?

Tags: html, hyperlink, leaflet

I defined in a style:

```
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content {
max:Height: 500px;
...
}
```

I would like to change the default color (which is blue) of a hyperlink within the popup and **only** within the popup.

How to supersede the default color ?
Thank you by advance

Note 1: I found this:

```
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content a {
color:red;
}
```

But the text and the underline are red ! I would like the text in red and the underline in white

Note 2: according to @Falke design

```
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content a {
color:red;
text-decoration: none;
}
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content a:hover {
color:red;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

The text is red, no underlined OK
On mouse over: the text is red, underlined in red and underlined in white !!!??? why a double underline ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bottom-border to the text.

```
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content a {
    color:red;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: why a double underline ?

Comment: with `text-decoration:none;` it should only one underline visible